# Angular 2 : Pass URL as Parameter to Route

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular, routes

I am trying to pass a URL as Parameter. It works when i use

```
this._r.navigate(['/videos', { id : url}]);
```

Actually the below video details load with that above url. but when i reload the page. it shows the second image. that's pretty bad. is there a way or workaround to solve this ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please show us how you get the id parameter?

Comment: on @routes do you mean ? 

`@Routes ([
    { path : "/videos", component : VideoComponent },
])`

havent used "/:id" as the link will be broken with two urls inside

Comment: I mean in your `VideoComponent`, you are getting the url parameter, that's what I want to see.

Comment: this is how it is `this.videoURL = this._rs.getParam('id');` rs is RouteSegment

Comment: @Shakee93 It seems that your webserver throwing that error not Angular2.

Comment: Probably the Server / Browser they get it as a broken URL. i have tried with php `http://domain.com/aplace?param=thing&param=url` it works as the pattern is different this breaks